# Ghost line/barrier showing in Altium deginer

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-layers, routing, trace

I am having a problem where there's an area (line) that appears only while running traces and on the draftsman document. the ghost line/region does not show up on any of the layers, I toggled all the layers and navigated through all of them and it does show up.

The region is keeping me from routing through regardless of the layer I'm routing through it.

It's not a component or a trace as I tried the find similar objects for both.

[image: Bottom Layer]

[image]

Comment: Have you also enabled the Keep-Out Layers?

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Comment: as per @ChrisKnudsen ... here is a clickable link https://forum.live.altium.com ... Chris, if you add **https://** then link becomes clickable

Answer (score 0):

It was a very small board cutout. it could only be selected by selecting all. after only showing the board outline view and Ctrl+A and only selecting "Regions" I was able to delete it and then redefine the cutouts.